# Complicated filtering of data frame without loops

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, filtering

I have big data frame with positions, time stamps, trip ids etc.

I would like to in a simple way, to avoid double loops, filter out and save only some of the rows.

So for all the rows that have the same combination of trip_id and stop_id, I want to save the row where the speed was first equal to zero. Either by take the minimum timestamp where the speed is zero or simple just the first time the speed is zero since the frame is ordered by the timestamp.

So in the example below, I would like to find the three top rows (in the real data frame a lot more rows) and just save the second row where the speed first was zero.

Is there a way to do this without any loops?

```
trip_id.x          stop_id          latitude.x         longitude.x        bearing speed  timestamp       vehicle id
55700000048910944 9022005000050006  58.416879999999999 15.624510000000001      30   0.2 1541399400 9031005990005424
55700000048910944 9022005000050006  58.416879999999999 15.624510000000001       0     0 1541399401 9031005990005424
55700000048910944 9022005000050006  58.416879999999999 15.624510000000001       0     0 1541399402 9031005990005424
55700000048910300 9022005000050006  58.416879999999999 15.624510000000001      30   0.5 1541400000 9031005990005424
```

Edit:
Here is the dput() of a longer exampel with a simpler format of the data I have:

```
    structure(list(trip_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3), stop_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), speed = c(5, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 
5, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 4
), timestamp = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 102, 103, 104, 201, 202, 203, 
204, 301, 302, 303, 304, 401, 402, 403, 404, 501, 502, 503, 504, 
601, 602, 603, 604, 701, 702, 703, 704, 801, 802, 803, 804)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the wanted output:

```
    structure(list(trip_id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), stop_id = c(1, 
3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), speed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), timestamp = c(2, 
202, 302, 402, 502, 602, 702, 802)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Edit: Trying to change to code to have conditions in it. Tried with case_when and if but can't get it to work:

```
df_arrival_z <- df %>%
  group_by(trip_id, stop_id) %>%
  filter(speed == 0)
  # Check if there is any rows where speed is zero
  if (nrow(filter(speed == 0)) > 0){
    # Take the first row if there is rows with zero
    filter(speed == 0) %>% slice(1)
  }
  if (nrow(filter(speed == 0)) == 0){
    # Take the middle point if there is no rows with speed = 0
    slice(nrow%/%2)
  }
```

Comment: Hi, yould you please show the code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide a bit bigger sample of your data with `dput()`?

Comment: @PawełChabros, the df is 3600 rows and 25 columns , the dput() couldn't show all the data. I tried to provied just the minimum needed to understand the problem. How much more would you like to see?

Comment: @jay.sf I haven't really tried since the only way I can think of is loops, so I thought I would ask here first.

Comment: hi! this seems fairly easy with `dplyr` library. But I think you should try to create a simple example with fake numbers and the desired output to make this more clear.

Comment: @RLave, I added a simple example of some more data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without desired output I can't be sure what you expect, but try this and let me know:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(trip_id, stop_id) %>%
  filter(speed == 0) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. I added some output from dput() with some made up data and my wanted result.

Comment: I've eddited my answer. Check it now.

Comment: It worked as I wanted. Thank you very much! Is there a way to slice by the last row of the filtered values? I want to find the row where the speed is greater than zero again, after it have been zero. (Basicly, when did the bus departure from the bus stop)

Comment: Yes. To get last value of each group do this: `... %>%
  slice(which.max(row_number()))
`

Comment: Thanks. 

I tried to change the code a bit, but I get an error. Here is the code:
  `df_arrival_z <- df %>%
  group_by(trip_id, stop_id) %>%
  filter(speed == 0)
  # Check if there is any rows where speed is zero
  if (nrow(filter(speed == 0)) > 0){
    # Take the first row if there is rows with zero
    filter(speed == 0) %>% slice(1)
  }
  if (nrow(filter(speed == 0)) == 0){
    # Take the middle point if there is no rows with speed = 0
    slice(nrow%/%2)
  } `
But I get the error `Error in filter(speed == 0) : object 'speed' not found`